# Is there a way to change the position of the top menu bar?

Tags: customization, panel

I'd like to know if there's a way to put the menu bar in the bottom, instead of it being in the top.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but changing the menu bar position is not possible in unity desktop environment. It is designed to be same on all systems.

But If you need customization, you may try other desktop environment like gnome-shell, gnome-classic-desktop, KDE etc. In gnome you can easily drag it using "super+alt".