# Change start menu position in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments, menu, cinnamon

How can I change the start menu position from bottom of the screen to top of the screen on Cinnamon Ubuntu. I kept searching this and did not found any info regarding this issue.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/637854/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-position-of-the-top-menu-bar

Answer (score 1):

Change from the Panel properties, right click on the panel and position it to the top.

Comment: https://beta.postimg.org/image/dky49i0lh/ and https://beta.postimg.org/image/qntqsrqth/ don't see any, also right clicked on the panel and there is a menu that says maximize/minimize/resize/move.

Comment: Ah managed to find out. You need to click right on the start menu bar and after Modify panel and Move Panel.